# Is there a benefit of having IdentityServer standing behind an API?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm about to implement the authentication module of my ASP.NET Core application.

I think I already know the answer for the following question, but I just want to make sure I am right, because I have been wrong before about some conceptions of IdentityServer.

**Question:** Is there ANY benefit of having the clients go through a single-point API that will centralize the access to the IdentityServer?

**Answer(?):** From what I understand, the IdentityServer is an implementation of the STS in the OpenIDConnect protocol, and the IdentityModel different libraries are yet again an implementation of the protocol, in the client side. 
Therefore, even if I replace my IdentityServer with antoher STS - my clients won't have to change, if I configure my new STS to behave the same.

Can anyone approve the above? I'd rather make the mistakes now and not after I start :)

Comment: I am trying to understand your question, are you trying to add an intermediary between external clients and your STS? where the intermediary delegates access but it uses IDS to do that?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you described, but for all of my clients, not only the externals. I am thinking if there's an added value by doing that (for instance if I want to replace the IDS with another STS that supports OIDC).
I'm thinking no, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: IdentityServer is an implementation of OIDC, you can in theory replace IdentityServer with any other provider that implements OIDC. In short, if your STS was IDS4 you can replace it with any provider that is certified for at least the first 4 OP modes as seen here -> http://openid.net/certification/

Comment: Great! Just wanted to make sure :)
Thanks for the answer and for the link